# Handling exceptions of Quartz.NET scheduler embedded in a windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET as an embedded scheduler for my windows service.

Quartz is configured to use `AdoJobStore` and every time the SQL server is not available for whatever reason, Quartz throws `Quartz.JobPersistenceException` exception which kills my windows service.

Obviously, Quartz `IScheduler` is instantiated and started from within a `try...catch` block from within the `OnStart` of my service but once the `IScheudler` is up and running any exceptions thrown by Quartz are no longer caught by that `catch` block...

Any ideas on how to prevent Quartz exceptions from killing my windows service in this scenario are welcome...

I am aware that I can set the service to restart after crashing in the Recovery tab of the service but it is a patch, not really a solution...

EDIT:

These exceptions are thrown from within `ConnectionAndTransactionHolder` method of the `JobStoreSupport` class of the Quartz.NET library when the method fails to get and open a DB connection or a call to `BeginTransaction` fails. Since Quartz.NET is open source and I have access to this code I could just comment out the code that throws these `JobPersistenceException` exceptions but without analyzing in detail the source code of Quartz.NET I have no idea what effect that would have and if Quartz would continue to try scanning for triggers until the DB connection is again available or not... also I'm not sure if the license agreement would allow for any modification of the source code...

Comment: Beef up your error reporting so you'll know where to put the try/catch.  Add an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  Don't remove this code after you figured it out.